# Python and C coupling

Tags: python, c

I tried loading C shared library .so in Python using ctypes.CDLL class (Linux). Here is the [link](http://vasudevkamath.blogspot.com/2010/07/python-and-c-coupling.html) to which tells what I did. As I see the documentation it says CDLL class assumes that function returns int types. I've a doubt here what if I need to return variable of type other than the int type from a function in C?. 
And to what extent we can use C functions in Python i mean what are the limits/restrictions on using C shared libraries and functions

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By *default*, it assumes int, but you can set [restype](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types) to any of the [supported types](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) to override that.  E.g., from the docs:

```
strchr.restype = c_char_p
```

This means that `strchr` returns a pointer to a char, which corresponds to a Python string (or `None`, for a `NULL` pointer).